# How can I stay on my IP longer than 10 minutes?

Tags: orbot

I need to stay on an IP for longer than ten minutes to finish a download. Can I tell Orbot to stay on the IP for a fixed time? I'm running Orfox on Orbot for Android. Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2):

You won't change IP mid-download.

Tor considers creating new circuits by looking at the 'dirtiness' of existing circuits. If a new connection request is received and the current circuit is more than 10 minutes old, it will build a new circuit for the connection. However any connections which are on the old (>10 minute) circuit will be unaffected.

If you are experiencing breaks in connectivity, it is unrelated to this property. Adjusting this property will make your circuits look different from all other Tor users and as such will potentially catastrophically affect your anonymity set, it is not recommended to do this.

Tor Browser uses the `KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth` `SOCKSPort` flag to achieve long-term sessions. Since Tor Browser uses SOCKS5 authentication to isolate connections between hosts, each time a new connection is made to the same host the "dirtiness" is reset to 0. This means that as long as connections are actively happening within the 10 minute period, the circuit will remain open indefinitely. This improves user experience for websites which link IP addresses to login sessions for Tor Browser users.

This may be the solution you are looking for but I am unsure if Orfox is yet using SOCKS5 isolation, as I understand it is still under heavy development but as explained above: **I do not believe that your problems are related to changes in circuit and you should look for other possible problems first.**